# How to combine multiple node js file into a single bundle using webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, bundle

I am trying to create a single bundle from multiple javascript file in a nodejs application.

The configuration I am using looks somewhat like this:

```
const path = require('path')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

'use strict';

module.exports = {
    externals: [nodeExternals({})],
    entry: './lib/index.js',
    output: {
        iife: false,
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
        filename: 'bundle.js', // <-- Important
    },
    target: 'node', // <-- Important
};
```

The problem is when I run `bundle.js command` instead for it to do what the command says, i get the full source of the file streamed into the terminal.

It seems the file contains some sort of IIFE that gets executed immediately. I set `iife: false` to false in the webpack configuration but that also did not make any difference.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Edit:

I am calling webpack by adding:
`bundle: webpack --config webpack.config.js` to script section in `package.json` and then I run `npm run bundle`

Comment: Can you share how you are calling the `webpack` command?

Comment: Updated the story to include this

Comment: Very strange. It seems to be working for me as it is without any issues with Webpack version 5.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vercel/ncc package to bundle all your Node.js code into one file.